# Lua : return table trough function is nil

Tags: lua, lua-table

I get the error: source_file.lua:5: attempt to call a nil value (global 'getCard')

i try to catch the right table in questCards which Index=name is the same as  the given string from objName

```
questCards={{['name']='test1',['creatureName']='test3'},{['name']='test2',['creatureName']='test4'}}
obj='test1'
card=getCard(obj)
card['creatureName']=nil --Only for test purpose
if card['creatureName']==nil then
    --do Somthing
end
function getCard(objName)
  for k,v in pairs(questCards) do
    if v['name']==objName then
      return v
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As Ihf has said, you're calling the `getCard()` function before you've defined it, so you need to move the function up above the call to it in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `getCard` is not defined at the point where it is called.

You need to define `getCard` before calling it.